# How to stop debugging in Android application in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, tabstop

I'm writing a simple Android application. I changed the "Java EE" perspective to "debug" and after tracing variables, I return to original perspective ( "Java EE" ) and stopped debugging. But when I try to run my application on my phone, it changes the perspective automatically to debug and jumps to first break point.
In debug window, it shows:
debugging

```
DalvikVM[localhost:8600]    
    Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 23 in FirstActivity))  
        FirstActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 23 
        Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity, Bundle) line: 1047   
        ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2627  
        ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 2679   
        ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityRecord, Intent) line: 125 
        ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 2033  
        ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
        Looper.loop() line: 123 
        ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
        Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
        ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 871  
        ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 629 
        NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]  
    Thread [<7> Binder Thread #2] (Running) 
    Thread [<6> Binder Thread #1] (Running)
```

Would you please help me how get rid of this debug perspective ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you launching the application? If you're using a shortcut, make sure you're doing `Run As... Android Application` rather than `Debug As... Android Application`. I'm out of practice, but I believe the shortcut for `Run As` in Eclipse is Ctrl+F11?

Answer (score 10):

Suggestions:

- When you right click the project, make sure you select 'Run as' rather than 'Debug as'
- While in the debug perspective, click the icon to disconnect the debugger (In my eclipse, it's the icon to the right of the Stop icon)
- Disable all breakpoints

Comment: i clicked on Disconnect, it solved my endless issue ... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove or disable the breakpoint on `FirstActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line: 23`

Alternatively, restart your app using a Run Configuration from the Eclipse menu instead of a Debug config.

Comment: Please note I changed the perspective to "Java EE", and it's no longer in debug mode, so It should not break, even without removing break points. Right?

Comment: No, it'll still break even if you go back to the Java EE perspective.  Note you can manage breakpoints (right-click on line) even in the normal development perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I kept getting the debug perspective despite all the having configured all the settings that were posted above.

I found an answer on another StackOverflow:
Reboot your debugging device.

(Don't power off, instead choose Reboot).
That worked for me.